# What data structure to use to have O(log n) key AND value lookup?

Tags: data-structures, big-o, key-value, binary-search

Having a sorted dict (hash table, map or whatever key/value structure) you can easily have a binary search to look for an item. If we assume the keys are unique but values could be repeated, what data structure can we use to have O(log n) retrieval for keys and also O(log n) query to find count of `values=something` in the given data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two binary search trees, one for keys, second for values, with mutual pointers will provide the required functionality. The pointers can be many-to-one from keys to values and one-to-many from values to keys.

Comment: Was thinking the same but is it not tricky to keep two trees synced?

Comment: It depends what kind of manipulation you want to implement. For example, delete by value might be a little tricky, but not impossible (also you need to define, how exactly should it work, since the values are not unique).