# What is the most efficient data structure to build a large word-to-index-to-word dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, trie, nlp

I would like to index a very large number of strings (mapping each string to an numeric value) but also be able to retrieve each string from its numeric index.

Using hash tables or python dict is not an option because of memory issues so I decided to use a [radix trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to store the strings, I can retrieve the index of any string very quickly and handle a very large number of strings.

My problem is that I also need to retrieve the strings from their numeric index, and if I maintain a "reverse index" list [string1, string2, ..., stringn] I'll loose the memory benefit of the Trie.

I thought maybe the "reverse index" could be a list of pointers to the last node of a kind-of Trie structure but first, there are no pointers in python, and second I'm not sure I can have a "node-level" access to the Trie structure I'm currently using.

Does this kind of data-structure already exists? And if not how would you do this in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What data structure to use to have O(log n) key AND value lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356948/what-data-structure-to-use-to-have-olog-n-key-and-value-lookup)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127290/data-structure-for-fast-full-text-search

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev nope, operations in tries are usually O(k) where k is the length of the key, and in my case the index values are unique...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering to myself because I finally end up creating my own data-structure which is perfectly suited for the word-to-index-to-word problem I had, using only python3 built-in functions.

I tried to make it clean and efficient but there's obviously room for improvement and a C binding would be better.

So the final result is a indexedtrie class that looks like a python dict (or defaultdict if you invoke it with a default_factory parameter) but can also be queried like a list because a kind of "reversed index" is automatically maintained.

The keys, which are stored in an internal radix trie, can be any subscriptable object (bytes, strings, tuples, lists) and the values you want to store anything you want inside.

Also the indextrie class is pickable, and you can benefit from the advantages of radix tries regarding "prefix search" and this kind of things!

Each key in the trie is associated with a unique integer index, you can retrieve the key with the index or the index with the key and the whole thing is fast and memory safe so I personally think that's one of the best data-structure in the world and that it should be integrated in python standard library :).

Enough talking, here is the code, feel free to adapt and use it:

```
"""
A Python3 indexed trie class.
An indexed trie's key can be any subscriptable object. 
Keys of the indexed trie are stored using a "radix trie", a space-optimized data-structure which has many advantages (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree).
Also, each key in the indexed trie is associated to a unique index which is build dynamically.

Indexed trie is used like a python dictionary (and even a collections.defaultdict if you want to) but its values can also be accessed or updated (but not created) like a list!

Example:
    >>> t = indextrie()
    >>> t["abc"] = "hello"
    >>> t[0]
    'hello'
    >>> t["abc"]
    'hello'
    >>> t.index2key(0)
    'abc'
    >>> t.key2index("abc")
    0
    >>> t[:]
    [0]
    >>> print(t)
    {(0, 'abc'): hello}
"""

__author__ = "@fbparis"

_SENTINEL = object()

class _Node(object):
    """
    A single node in the trie.
    """
    __slots__ = "_children", "_parent", "_index", "_key"

    def __init__(self, key, parent, index=None):
        self._children = set()
        self._key = key
        self._parent = parent
        self._index = index
        self._parent._children.add(self)

class IndexedtrieKey(object):
    """
    A pair (index, key) acting as an indexedtrie's key
    """
    __slots__ = "index", "key"

    def __init__(self, index, key):
        self.index = index
        self.key = key

    def __repr__(self):
        return "(%d, %s)" % (self.index, self.key)

class indexedtrie(object):
    """
    The indexed trie data-structure.
    """
    __slots__ = "_children", "_indexes", "_values", "_nodescount", "_default_factory"

    def __init__(self, items=None, default_factory=_SENTINEL):
        """
        A list of items can be passed to initialize the indexed trie.
        """
        self._children = set()
        self.setdefault(default_factory)
        self._indexes = []
        self._values = []
        self._nodescount = 0 # keeping track of nodes count is purely informational
        if items is not None:
            for k, v in items:
                if isinstance(k, IndexedtrieKey):
                    self.__setitem__(k.key, v)
                else:
                    self.__setitem__(k, v)

    @classmethod
    def fromkeys(cls, keys, value=_SENTINEL, default_factory=_SENTINEL):
        """
        Build a new indexedtrie from a list of keys.
        """
        obj = cls(default_factory=default_factory)
        for key in keys:
            if value is _SENTINEL:
                if default_factory is not _SENTINEL:
                    obj[key] = obj._default_factory()
                else:
                    obj[key] = None
            else:
                obj[key] = value
        return obj

    @classmethod
    def fromsplit(cls, keys, value=_SENTINEL, default_factory=_SENTINEL):
        """
        Build a new indexedtrie from a splitable object.
        """
        obj = cls(default_factory=default_factory)
        for key in keys.split():
            if value is _SENTINEL:
                if default_factory is not _SENTINEL:
                    obj[key] = obj._default_factory()
                else:
                    obj[key] = None
            else:
                obj[key] = value
        return obj

    def setdefault(self, factory=_SENTINEL):
        """
        """
        if factory is not _SENTINEL:
            # indexed trie will act like a collections.defaultdict except in some cases because the __missing__
            # method is not implemented here (on purpose).
            # That means that simple lookups on a non existing key will return a default value without adding
            # the key, which is the more logical way to do.
            # Also means that if your default_factory is for example "list", you won't be able to create new
            # items with "append" or "extend" methods which are updating the list itself.
            # Instead you have to do something like trie["newkey"] += [...]
            try:
                _ = factory()
            except TypeError:
                # a default value is also accepted as default_factory, even "None"
                self._default_factory = lambda: factory
            else:
                self._default_factory = factory
        else:
            self._default_factory = _SENTINEL

    def copy(self):
        """
        Return a pseudo-shallow copy of the indexedtrie.
        Keys and nodes are deepcopied, but if you store some referenced objects in values, only the references will be copied.
        """
        return self.__class__(self.items(), default_factory=self._default_factory)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._indexes)

    def __repr__(self):
        if self._default_factory is not _SENTINEL:
            default = ", default_value=%s" % self._default_factory()
        else:
            default = ""
        return "<%s object at %s: %d items, %d nodes%s>" % (self.__class__.__name__, hex(id(self)), len(self), self._nodescount, default)

    def __str__(self):
        ret = ["%s: %s" % (k, v) for k, v in self.items()]
        return "{%s}" % ", ".join(ret)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.keys()

    def __contains__(self, key_or_index):
        """
        Return True if the key or index exists in the indexed trie.
        """
        if isinstance(key_or_index, IndexedtrieKey):
            return key_or_index.index >= 0 and key_or_index.index < len(self)
        if isinstance(key_or_index, int):
            return key_or_index >= 0 and key_or_index < len(self)
        if self._seems_valid_key(key_or_index):
            try:
                node = self._get_node(key_or_index)
            except KeyError:
                return False
            else:
                return node._index is not None
        raise TypeError("invalid key type")

    def __getitem__(self, key_or_index):
        """
        """
        if isinstance(key_or_index, IndexedtrieKey):
            return self._values[key_or_index.index]
        if isinstance(key_or_index, int) or isinstance(key_or_index, slice):
            return self._values[key_or_index]
        if self._seems_valid_key(key_or_index):
            try:
                node = self._get_node(key_or_index)
            except KeyError:
                if self._default_factory is _SENTINEL:
                    raise
                else:
                    return self._default_factory()
            else:
                if node._index is None:
                    if self._default_factory is _SENTINEL:
                        raise KeyError
                    else:
                        return self._default_factory()
                else:
                    return self._values[node._index]            
        raise TypeError("invalid key type")

    def __setitem__(self, key_or_index, value):
        """
        """
        if isinstance(key_or_index, IndexedtrieKey):
            self._values[key_or_index.index] = value
        elif isinstance(key_or_index, int):
            self._values[key_or_index] = value
        elif isinstance(key_or_index, slice):
            raise NotImplementedError
        elif self._seems_valid_key(key_or_index):
            try:
                node = self._get_node(key_or_index)
            except KeyError:
                # create a new node
                self._add_node(key_or_index, value)
            else:
                if node._index is None:
                    # if node exists but not indexed, we index it and update the value
                    self._add_to_index(node, value)
                else:
                    # else we update its value
                    self._values[node._index] = value
        else:
            raise TypeError("invalid key type")

    def __delitem__(self, key_or_index):
        """
        """
        if isinstance(key_or_index, IndexedtrieKey):
            node = self._indexes[key_or_index.index]
        elif isinstance(key_or_index, int):
            node = self._indexes[key_or_index]
        elif isinstance(key_or_index, slice):
            raise NotImplementedError
        elif self._seems_valid_key(key_or_index):
            node = self._get_node(key_or_index)
            if node._index is None:
                raise KeyError
        else:
            raise TypeError("invalid key type")
        # switch last index with deleted index (except if deleted index is last index)
        last_node, last_value = self._indexes.pop(), self._values.pop()
        if node._index != last_node._index:
            last_node._index = node._index
            self._indexes[node._index] = last_node
            self._values[node._index] = last_value
        if len(node._children) > 1:
            #case 1: node has more than 1 child, only turn index off
            node._index = None
        elif len(node._children) == 1:
            # case 2: node has 1 child
            child = node._children.pop()
            child._key = node._key + child._key
            child._parent = node._parent
            node._parent._children.add(child)
            node._parent._children.remove(node)
            del(node)
            self._nodescount -= 1
        else:
            # case 3: node has no child, check the parent node
            parent = node._parent
            parent._children.remove(node)
            del(node)
            self._nodescount -= 1
            if hasattr(parent, "_index"):
                if parent._index is None and len(parent._children) == 1:
                    node = parent._children.pop()
                    node._key = parent._key + node._key
                    node._parent = parent._parent
                    parent._parent._children.add(node)
                    parent._parent._children.remove(parent)
                    del(parent)
                    self._nodescount -= 1

    @staticmethod
    def _seems_valid_key(key):
        """
        Return True if "key" can be a valid key (must be subscriptable).
        """
        try:
            _ = key[:0]
        except TypeError:
            return False
        return True

    def keys(self, prefix=None):
        """
        Yield keys stored in the indexedtrie where key is a IndexedtrieKey object.
        If prefix is given, yield only keys of items with key matching the prefix.
        """
        if prefix is None:
            for i, node in enumerate(self._indexes):
                yield IndexedtrieKey(i, self._get_key(node))
        else:
            if self._seems_valid_key(prefix):
                empty = prefix[:0]
                children = [(empty, prefix, child) for child in self._children]
                while len(children):
                    _children = []
                    for key, prefix, child in children:
                        if prefix == child._key[:len(prefix)]:
                            _key = key + child._key
                            _children.extend([(_key, empty, _child) for _child in child._children])
                            if child._index is not None:
                                yield IndexedtrieKey(child._index, _key)
                        elif prefix[:len(child._key)] == child._key:
                            _prefix = prefix[len(child._key):]
                            _key = key + prefix[:len(child._key)]
                            _children.extend([(_key, _prefix, _child) for _child in child._children])
                    children = _children
            else:
                raise ValueError("invalid prefix type")

    def values(self, prefix=None):
        """
        Yield values stored in the indexedtrie.
        If prefix is given, yield only values of items with key matching the prefix.
        """
        if prefix is None:
            for value in self._values:
                yield value
        else:
            for key in self.keys(prefix):
                yield self._values[key.index]

    def items(self, prefix=None):
        """
        Yield (key, value) pairs stored in the indexedtrie where key is a IndexedtrieKey object.
        If prefix is given, yield only (key, value) pairs of items with key matching the prefix.
        """
        for key in self.keys(prefix):
            yield key, self._values[key.index]

    def show_tree(self, node=None, level=0):
        """
        Pretty print the internal trie (recursive function).
        """
        if node is None:
            node = self
        for child in node._children:
            print("-" * level + "<key=%s, index=%s>" % (child._key, child._index))
            if len(child._children):
                self.show_tree(child, level + 1)

    def _get_node(self, key):
        """
        Return the node associated to key or raise a KeyError.
        """
        children = self._children
        while len(children):
            notfound = True
            for child in children:
                if key == child._key:
                    return child
                if child._key == key[:len(child._key)]:
                    children = child._children
                    key = key[len(child._key):]
                    notfound = False
                    break
            if notfound:
                break
        raise KeyError

    def _add_node(self, key, value):
        """
        Add a new key in the trie and updates indexes and values.
        """
        children = self._children
        parent = self
        moved = None
        done = len(children) == 0
        # we want to insert key="abc"
        while not done:
            done = True
            for child in children:
                # assert child._key != key # uncomment if you don't trust me
                if child._key == key[:len(child._key)]:
                    # case 1: child's key is "ab", insert "c" in child's children 
                    parent = child
                    children = child._children
                    key = key[len(child._key):]
                    done = len(children) == 0
                    break
                elif key == child._key[:len(key)]:
                    # case 2: child's key is "abcd", we insert "abc" in place of the child
                    # child's parent will be the inserted node and child's key is now "d"
                    parent = child._parent
                    moved = child
                    parent._children.remove(moved)
                    moved._key = moved._key[len(key):]
                    break
                elif type(key) is type(child._key): # don't mess it up
                    # find longest common prefix
                    prefix = key[:0]
                    for i, c in enumerate(key):
                        if child._key[i] != c:
                            prefix = key[:i]
                            break
                    if prefix:
                        # case 3: child's key is abd, we spawn a new node with key "ab"
                        # to replace child ; child's key is now "d" and child's parent is 
                        # the new created node.
                        # the new node will also be inserted as a child of this node
                        # with key "c"
                        node = _Node(prefix, child._parent)
                        self._nodescount += 1
                        child._parent._children.remove(child)
                        child._key = child._key[len(prefix):]
                        child._parent = node
                        node._children.add(child)
                        key = key[len(prefix):]
                        parent = node
                        break
        # create the new node
        node = _Node(key, parent)
        self._nodescount += 1
        if moved is not None:
            # if we have moved an existing node, update it
            moved._parent = node
            node._children.add(moved)
        self._add_to_index(node, value)

    def _get_key(self, node):
        """
        Rebuild key from a terminal node.
        """
        key = node._key
        while node._parent is not self:
            node = node._parent
            key = node._key + key
        return key

    def _add_to_index(self, node, value):
        """
        Add a new node to the index.
        Also record its value.
        """
        node._index = len(self)
        self._indexes.append(node)
        self._values.append(value)

    def key2index(self, key):
        """
        key -> index
        """
        if self._seems_valid_key(key):
            node = self._get_node(key)
            if node._index is not None:
                return node._index
            raise KeyError
        raise TypeError("invalid key type")

    def index2key(self, index):
        """
        index or IndexedtrieKey -> key.
        """
        if isinstance(index, IndexedtrieKey):
            index = index.index
        elif not isinstance(index, int):
            raise TypeError("index must be an int")
        if index < 0 or index > len(self._indexes):
            raise IndexError
        return self._get_key(self._indexes[index])
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [What data structure to use to have O(log n) key AND value lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356948/what-data-structure-to-use-to-have-olog-n-key-and-value-lookup) , you need two synchronized data structures for key and value lookups, each holding references to the other's leaf nodes.

The structure for the ID lookup can be anything with sufficient efficientcy -- a balanced tree, a hash table, another trie.

To be able to extract the value from a leaf node reference, a trie needs to allow 1) leaf node references themselves (not necessarily a real Python reference, anything that its API can use); 2) walking up the trie to extract the word from that reference.

Note that a reference is effectively a unique integer so if your IDs are not larger than an integer, it makes sense to reuse something as IDs -- e.g. the trie node references themselves. Then if the trie API can validate such a reference (i.e. tell if it has a used node with such a reference) this will act as the ID lookup and you don't need the 2nd structure at all! This way, the IDs will be non-persistent though 'cuz reference values (effectively memory addresses) change between processes and runs.